# sql, getting sub query data into table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

sorry for the bad title. not sure how to describe this.

i have a table `users`, which has:

```
 userID |   firstname  | lastname
```

then I have a second table, called `userColors`, which records each users favourite colors: each user could have one color, or many:

```
 id | userID | colorID
```

and then the `colors` table:

```
 colorID | colorName
```

i currently export a long list of users, with each color getting its own row. so some users will have one row, some will have multiple rows.

what i would like to try now, is having each user on one row, with the list of favourite colors in the final columns (either each in its own row - or - in the same column, just comma separated). such as:

```
userID | firstname | lastName  | colors
------------------------------------------------
  2    |  harry    | smith     | red
  3    |  larry    | whatever  | blue, yellow
```

OR:

```
userID | firstname | lastName  | color1  | color2  | color_as_many_as_needed....
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  2    |  harry    | smith     | red
  3    |  larry    | whatever  | blue    |  yellow
```

i guess the answer is a sub query, but not sure how to join it....

Comment: Actually the answer is a pivot query.  Google "sql server pivot query" and you will find some examples.

Comment: If you want to do this in a query, it is possible. If you want to change from related data to tables with this horrible structure, then don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/46122/3/0) demonstrating the below query:

```
SELECT u.*, 
colors = STUFF((
          SELECT ', ' + c.colorName
          FROM userColors AS uc
          INNER JOIN colors AS c ON uc.colorID = c.colorID
          WHERE u.userID = uc.UserID
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM users AS u
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you a hint:

```
select 'test' as Test, 1 as Item 
into #test 
union select 'test2', 2 
union select 'test', 3 
union select 'test', 5 

select t2.test, STUFF((SELECT  ', ' + cast(t1.Item as varchar (10) )
        FROM #test t1 where t2.test = t1.test 
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') 
     from #test t2
     group by t2.test
```